# How to make this query in sqlalchemy?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
SELECT
  maintener.*,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM device d
     WHERE d.in_stock_maintener_id = maintener.id) AS in_stock_devices
FROM maintener;
```

I'm creating a report that show all mainteners but i need to show the number of devices that each one of that mainteners has by looking at the devices model reference in_stock_maintener_id;

I have this models in my persist sqlalchemy.

```
class Maintener(persist.Base):
    __tablename__ = 'maintener'

      id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
      name = Column(String(255))
      document_number = Column(String(30))
      phone_1 = Column(String(12))
      phone_2 = Column(String(12))
      email = Column(String(255))




class Device(persist.Base):

    __tablename__ = 'device'

      id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
      serial = Column(String(45))
      in_stock = Column(SmallInteger)
      in_stock_maintener_id = Column(ForeignKey(u'maintener.id'), nullable=True, index=True)

    in_stock_maintener = relationship(u'Maintener', lazy='noload', \
      primaryjoin='Device.in_stock_maintener_id == Maintener.id')
```

If anyone could help me, i'll be grateful =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sq = (
    session
    .query(func.count())
    .select_from(Device)
    .filter(Device.in_stock_maintener_id == Maintener.id)
).as_scalar()

q = session.query(Maintener, sq.label('in_stock_devices'))
```

Query above will return an enumerable of `tuple(Maintener, Integer)`.

If you would like to have columns instead (as per your comment), then you can either specify the columns you want in the query implicitly:

```
q = session.query(Maintener.id, Maintener.name, sq.label('in_stock_devices'))
```

or if you would like all columns (as in `SELECT *`), then you could query the `Table` instead of the mapped entity:

```
q = session.query(Maintener.__table__, sq.label('in_stock_devices'))
```

*Above I assumed that you use `declarative` extension.*

Comment: Hi van, your anwser help me, but i got this result:

[(<persist.maintenance.Maintener object at 0x7f89c48f9278>, 2), (<persist.maintenance.Maintener object at 0x7f89c48f92e8>, 0), (<persist.maintenance.Maintener object at 0x7f89c48f9358>, 0)]

How can i get the 2, 0 and 0 inside the persist.maintenance.Maintener.object resulting this:

[<persist.maintenance.Maintener object at 0x7f89c48f9278>, (<persist.maintenance.Maintener object at 0x7f89c48f92e8>, (<persist.maintenance.Maintener object at 0x7f89c48f9358>] like in_stock_devices is one atribute of persist.maintenance.Maintener.